# AutoLayout with rotated UI Elements

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, autolayout

I've been teaching myself `Auto Layout` using code (i.e. avoiding Interface Builder).

I have a view that I'd like to set up with `Auto Layout`.

It has 3 `UILabels` that are horizontal and one that is vertical.

```
Sort of like this.
---------------------------------------------
| ---  -----------------------------------  |
| | |  |                                 |  |
| | |  -----------------------------------  |
| | |  -----------------------------------  |
| | |  |                                 |  |
| | |  -----------------------------------  |
| | |  -----------------------------------  |
| | |  |                                 |  |
| ---  -----------------------------------  |
---------------------------------------------
```

The label on the left is rotated 90 degrees to the left.

I'm just not sure how to apply auto layout between the rotated label and the non-rotated labels?

Can this be done?

Does the `height` become the `width`, does the `top` become the `left`, etc...

Comment: +1 great question. If you have the "top" attached to the Superview (in IB) and you rotate the view 90 degrees does the constraint remain attached to the rotated side or stay attached to the new "top"?  If the latter, you can drop your view into IB, attach the constraints between the view and the top-right view; then rotate in your view controller. But I don't actually know the answer to this.

Comment: Thanks, I've had to do all the layout for this manually but it would be great to get an answer to this and throw all the layout into auto layout.

Comment: I suppose it all depends on how the constraint (linked to the frame) responds to changes in the view's CTM. I would expect the constraints to ignore the CTM rotations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably a “right” answer, but an easy workaround would be to add the rotated labels as subviews of non-rotated views, and do your layout with those views.

**Update:** I just remembered that when a view has a transform applied, the frame becomes the smallest possible bounding frame*. Unless I'm mistaken, that means the frame would be exactly what you want it to be, and assuming the layout calculations are based on the frame, it should work as expected.

* when I last worked with transformed views, the frame of a rotated view was undefined, but experimentation showed that it was the bounding rect of the rotated view. Not sure if it is now defined or expressly allowed/forbidden.

**Update 2:** I checked the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame), and they still have a strongly worded warning against doing this:

> **Warning:** If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Comment: OK, don't know why I didn't try this before but I built a small test project ad set up the main view like in my question... worked perfectly. You're right it seems that the AutoLayout "frame" is in fact the minimal bounding box of the view after rotation.

Comment: I checked the docs, and updated my answer with the warning that’s still there. If it works, great, but double check it every time there’s an OS update.