# UIView with rotation not resizing

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uilabel

I've created `UIView` Containing `UILabel` inside (as suggested in: [AutoLayout with rotated UI Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344217/autolayout-with-rotated-ui-elements)). The problem is that it does not want to autolayout when I rotate it by 90 degrees (see pictures).

Image before rotation:
[image: Image before rotation]

and after:

[image]

Rotation is done by:

```
yTitleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
yTitleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (-3.14/2);
```

Constraints between `SleepScoreUILabel` and blue `UIView` are just to keep some distance between them:

[image]

**EDIT1:**
Tried with suggestions of @bennegeek

```
 yTitleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
    CGRect frame = yTitleLabel.frame;
    bottom.active = NO;
    top.active = NO;
    leading.active = NO;
    trailing.active = NO;
    yTitleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (-M_PI/2);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        yTitleLabel.frame = frame;
    });
```

But the result is:
[image]

If after those operations I turn the constraints back active, I get:
[image]

Comment: You need to remove the constraints before performing the transform.

Comment: After deactivating them, the view is being drawn (with new proper size :D) in (0,0) of the screen (not the view)...

Comment: Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true. Store the frame in a variable. Then remove the constraints. Set the frame again in a dispatch to main queue.

Comment: Tried with your suggestions. See edit1. There is no blue rectangle (titleView is not drawn properly and therefore other views are also not laid out properly).